# Python, pandas - Why discrepancies in totals of unique item counts pivot_table vs groupby

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, pivot-table, unique, counting

I have a data set with individuals participating multiple times. I would like to count the unique number of individuals by gender. I've done this with a pivot_table and groupby approach and get different values. I can't figure out why. Can you tell me the obvious element which I have overlooked?

Pivot table solution:
[image]

Groupby solution:
[image]

As you can see, both give the correct values for the specific "gender". Rather, it is the totals that are different. Groupby appears to provide the correct totals whereas pivot_table totals seem off. Why?

Comment: Note: there are no NaNs in the dataset.

Answer (score 1):

This could be your issue. If there are names that are shared between Genders then `pivot_table` doesn't count the duplicates. groupby IS counting the duplicates as shown in this small example where the name 'A' is both 'M' and 'F' genders

```
import pandas as pd
import sidetable 

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Gender':['M','F','M','M','F','T','F','F'],
    'Name':  ['A','A','C','D','E','F','G','H'],
})

piv_df = df.pivot_table(index='Gender',values='Name',aggfunc=pd.Series.nunique,margins=True)
gb_df = df.groupby('Gender').agg({'Name':'nunique'}).stb.subtotal()

print(piv_df)
print(gb_df)
```

Output

```
        Name
Gender      
F          4
M          3
T          1
All        7
             Name
Gender           
F               4
M               3
T               1
grand_total     8
```

You can test this by `df = df.drop_duplicates('Name')` before the piv and gb and the counts should match if this is the only reason for the diff counts

Comment: Thanks! That was it. Great to know that pivot_table operates this way (actually as one would want it to do). Of course, my problems just got more challenging with some 3000 individuals reporting one way and now another. C’est la vie.